# Ruby how to use argv to pass url in command line?

Tags: ruby, command-line, http-headers

Let's assume my file name is *test.rb*

I would like to use `argv[0]` to access the first parameter and `argv[1]` to access the second parameter in my code to pass the url in the command line, something like this:

```
ruby test.rb http://www.www.youtypeitwepostit.com /messages
```

*test.rb* file contain:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI.parse('http://www.youtypeitwepostit.com')
http=Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/")
reply=http.request(request)
puts "#{reply.code} #{reply.message}"
reply.header.each_header {|key,value| puts "#{key}
= #{value}" }
puts "#{reply.body}"
```

Please teach me on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to pass the URL as a whole?

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI.parse(ARGV[0])
http=Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(ARGV[1])
reply=http.request(request)
puts "#{reply.code} #{reply.message}"
reply.header.each_header {|key,value| puts "#{key}
= #{value}" }
puts "#{reply.body}"
```

And then just call it with:

ruby test.rb http://www.youtypeitwepostit.com /messages

Answer (score 0):

With this command line, the url is the *first* parameter.

You can use it by accessing ARGV [0],

for example

```
uri = URI.parse(ARG[0])
```